# Connecting asp.net core web api application to SQL Server Database

Tags: sql-server, api, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

Good day!

I am new to asp.net core web api and I am trying to connect it to my local SQL Server DB. However, I am receiving an error on my Startup.cs file :

> "IServiceCollection does not contain a definition for AddDBContext".

Am I doing it right?

Here is my code in Startup.cs - ConfigureServices :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddCors();

    services.AddDbContext<MonsterContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseSqlServer("MyLocalDB");
    });

}
```

Also, here is my code in appsettings.json :

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },

  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyLocalDB": "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Inventory;User Id=sa;Password=Passw0rd;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;",
  } 
}
```

Here is the screen shot for my SQL Server Local DB :

[image]

I really don't know if I have not yet installed a Nuget package, or is there something missing in my code? I searched many times in google but unfortunately I am still receiving the error :( I will gladly appreciate any help / suggestions. Thank you very much and have a nice day guys!

Comment: EF core or dapper package should be installed, did u do it?

Comment: Hello Sir @MithunPattankar thank you for the response. I tried to install it but it returns an error "Package restore failed. Rolling back package..."

Comment: @MithunPattankar - would care to provide specific link to your blog where you deal with the problem described, or is it just blatant self promotion?

Comment: This blog post describes in detail by http://www.mithunvp.com/aspnet-core-web-api-entity-framework-core/

Comment: will check on this sir, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add (at least) Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection NuGet PAckage to your project, wich is part of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 2.0 already, probably this will fix your issue.

I said at least because you should also add the EntityFramework package.

I hope it helps,

Juan

Comment: Hi Sir @Juan , first of all thank you for the information. Also, I want to ask if Entity Framework is a prerequisite of asp.net core web api? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi @Gen, It is not a prerequisite because ypou can use EF or another ORM Like Dapper or perform direct queries coded by yourself... But as soon as you use DbContext (by inheritance), as DbContext is in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore package, then you have that dependency...

So, give it a try, install EntityFrameworkCore and Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, that should fix that issue you are having.